# Push data from ADLS Gen-2 to dedicated sql pool with pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've file in parquet format in ADLS Gen-2. I've loaded them in data frames using pyspark on spark pool.
I want to write the dataframes into the dedicated sql pool.
I've loaded using df= spark.read.load("file_path_in_adlsgen2",format="parquet")
Code for writing in ddsql pool?